# How to configure JWT auth in Envoy Proxy using Okta as provider

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, okta, envoyproxy

I have an app running behind envoy proxy and working on enabling JWT auth for the same using okta. It would be of great help if someone can point me to appropriate example configuration or appropriate document.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Gloo's ExtAuth functionality.